# MySQL query not returning all rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a leaderboard. Using the query below I get most, but *not* all player statistics returned. **It is missing the first row of the results.**.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE id = " . $playlist . " ORDER BY " . $statistic . " DESC LIMIT 100")
```

**RESOLVED**: I had **$user = mysql_fetch_array($query)** above the line **while($user = mysql_fetch_array($query)** resulting in the pointer being advanced by 1 row.

Comment: why are you restricting the query with id=$playlist?

Comment: @equinoxel, probably because they want all statistics rows for a _specific_ player. Although admittedly `playlist` sounds like a set of music tracks in an MP3 player :-)

Comment: but you only have 4 users ...

Comment: @paxdiablo from the page on the update, it looks like it's referring to a map/level? maybe a list of fields in the table or some sort of a dump would be more useful...

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE id = " . $playlist . " ORDER BY " . $statistic . " DESC LIMIT ".$offset.",".$limit);
```

//Also check how many rows in database

```
$total = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE id = " . $playlist);
echo mysql_num_rows($total);
```

Comment: I used your total number of rows suggestion and added it to a header on the web page that I linked to in the question. This should make the problem more apparent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting all the rows returned, it's probably due to the:

```
LIMIT 100
```

which will only retrieve 100 rows. The first thing to try is removing that from the query.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the results in that playlist, remove the `LIMIT 100`

To get all the results in the table, remove the `WHERE id = " . $playlist. "` and the `LIMIT 100`

Comment: The WHERE clause is necessary. I wish to limit it to 100 for when the database has more than 100 players/user.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT 100 means only return 100 results. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE id = '$playlist' ORDER BY '$statistic' LIMIT 0, 100")
```

Try this.